# Does typeorm support SQL IN clauses

Tags: typeorm

Does typeorm support SQL IN clauses? I'm trying to query a repository where a field matches 1 of multiple values.

```
myRepository.find({
    where: {
        SomeID: // IN [1, 2, 3, 4]
    }
});
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use QueryBuilder for this purpose:

```
const users = await userRepository.createQueryBuilder("user")
     .where("user.id IN (:...ids)", { ids: [1, 2, 3, 4] })
     .getMany();
```

Answer (score 6):

I'd just like to suggest another way.

```
const user = await this.usersRepository
.findOne(
    {
        where: { id: In([1, 2, 3]) }
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

You can now do this (from the docs):

```
import {In} from "typeorm";

const loadedPosts = await connection.getRepository(Post).find({
    title: In(["About #2", "About #3"])
});
```

will execute following query:

```
SELECT * FROM "post" WHERE "title" IN ('About #2','About #3')
```